# Происхождение слова "камин"

Tags: этимология

Искал происхождение слова "камин". Слово старинное, но изделие сравнительно недавнее. Может кто знает изначальное значение слова камин, гамаши.

Спасибо.

Comment: Камин или гамаши?

Comment: Кстати, где вы все это "искали"?  Любой этимологический словарь даст исчерпывающий ответ?

Comment: зачем Ваши речи, если в словарях ВСЁ сказано. Или чего нет в Коране... и т.д.

Comment: Не "зачем  наши речи", а "зачем Ваш вопрос".  Я правильно понимаю, что ни один словарь Вы даже не открывали, прежде чем вопрос задать? Корана, кстати, никто не касался.

Answer (score 6):

> Искал происхождение слова камин. Слово старинное...

Слово ***камин*** в русский язык вошло сравнительно недавно, в словарях ХI—ХVII вв. ещё не было отмечено.

Скорее всего, в русский вошло из немецкого ***der Kamin*** с тем же значением. Первоисточник — др.-греч. *κάμινος* "печь для обжига или плавки", "кухонная печь".